# Are there any code generators (inbuilt or third party) available to generate database first code for ASP..NET boilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am about to start development of a Cloud based product and am actively considering using ASPBoilerPlate. Apart from ASPZero, are there any tools or code generators that can generate Entity,Domain and DDOs for me... Are there any ASPBoilerplate specific code generators for other things like Simple Views for?

Answer (score 0):

some RAD tools have been developed but I personally think you have to implement your custom generators using T4 templates.

Comment: you're right. In this case, it can be done by the power of T4 templates.